# Datagridview.selectedrows.count always returning 0?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Trying this code on a data grid view (Already populated) object, I always get 0 selected rows when ever I make a selection.

```
Private Function IsThereASelection(ByVal e As DataGridView) As Boolean
            If e.SelectedRows.Count <> 0 Then
                MsgBox("You have selected " & e.SelectedRows.Count & " Rows.")
                IsThereASelection = True
    End If
                MsgBox("You have selected " & e.SelectedRows.Count & " Rows.")
                IsThereASelection = False
End Function
```

Some button code:

```
IsThereAselection(Window.DataGridView1)
```

[image]

Edit1: I've changed the datagridrow object selection mode to `FullRowSelect` but it doesn't work still.
Edit2: I was using the wrong reference in the button code (shown above). The correct reference would be DataGridView1 and that would be answer my question.

Comment: Are you sure you have a ´row´selected and not just a ´datagridcell´?

Comment: Yes, friend. Whenever I build the window, I point my mouse on the little triangle that selects the row and click on it.

Comment: Then you'll need to supply more code i'm afraid.

Comment: I've added a screen print?

Comment: Set the `SelectionMode` property to `FullRowSelect`.

Comment: Done that @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå. It doesn't work still.

Comment: Then you're not referencing the correct instance of `DataGridView1`. Show us where you invoke `IsThereAselection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting SelectionMode property to "FullRowSelect" solved my problem.